# AJAX/PHP Mulitple form POST submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am attempting to submit the form data to another page to be processed and am currently need receiving any data. Below are the forms in question. Default form is the login for requesting username/password. One submit button.

```
                <div id="form_wrapper" class="form_wrapper">
                <form class="register">
                    <h3>Register</h3>
                    <div>
                        <label>Username:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="regname"/>
                        <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" name="regpass" />
                        <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottom">
                        <div class="remember"><input type="checkbox" /><span>Keep me logged in</span></div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Register"></input>
                        <a href="index.html" rel="login" class="linkform">You have an account already? Log in here</a>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <form class="login active">
                    <h3>Login</h3>
                    <div>
                        <label>Username:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username"/>
                        <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Password: <a href="index.php" rel="forgot_password" class="forgot linkform">Forgot your password?</a></label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" />
                        <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottom">
                        <div class="remember"><input type="checkbox" /><span>Keep me logged in</span></div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Login"></input>
                        <a href="index.php" rel="register" class="linkform">You don't have an account yet? Register here</a>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <form class="forgot_password">
                    <h3>Forgot Password</h3>
                    <div>
                        <label>Username or Email:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="forgotuser" />
                        <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottom">
                        <input type="submit" value="Send reminder"></input>
                        <a href="index.php" rel="login" class="linkform">Suddenly remebered? Log in here</a>
                        <a href="index.php" rel="register" class="linkform">You don't have an account? Register here</a>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

I would like to submit what ever the current form data is

```
                $form_wrapper.find('input[type="submit"]')
                         .click(function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();
                              $.ajax({
                                    url: 'locallogin.php',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                                    success: function (results) {
                                      alert(results);
                                    }
                                    });
                         });
```

locallogin.php

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Right now the only response is an empty Array. Any ideas?

Comment: It should be `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: there is no PHP global variable `$POST` its `$_POST` and `$_GET` or both are `$_REQUEST`

Comment: ah. cant believe I didnt see that. Ok I fixed that and it still reports nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned previously, fix the `$(this)` and make it `$("#form_wrapper")` also fix the `$POST` to `$_POST`.  Your JS should look like this.

```
$('#form_wrapper').find('input[type="submit"]')
.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'locallogin.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).closest('form').serialize()+'&buttonName='+$(this).val(),
        success: function (results) {
            alert(results);
        }
    });
});
```

AFTER THE QUESTION ABOUT THE BUTTON NAME.

Added code to the data line of the ajax call.

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues - one as indicated in the comments - you need to use $_POST.

Another lies in,

```
data: $(this).serialize(),
```

$(this) is pointing to the button, so you are posting the serialized button. Try as follows :

```
data: $(".register").serialize(),
```

Comment: You don't want `$('#form_wrapper')` because that will include all the forms.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're serializing `$(this)` in the click even of an `input` element. You might want to use `data: $(this).closest('form').serialize()`. Second, it's `print_r($_POST)` (you're missing the underscore).

Comment: Whats the difference between data: $(this).closest('form').serialize()
and data: $("#form_wrapper").serialize(),